# CSS letter-spacing transition does not work in Firefox v26

Tags: css, firefox, transition

This transition works in Chrome and IE11 but not in Firefox v26 Win7.

[MDN specification says it's still in a working draft.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing#Specifications)

CSS-TRICKS says it's animatable without any note about not working in Firefox.

[This js fiddle demonstrates the behavior.](http://jsfiddle.net/8jAZy/3/)

Any ideas?

```
.trans {   
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s    
}

.spaced {    
    letter-spacing: 10px    
}

$("#btn").on('click', function() {
    $("h1").toggleClass("spaced");
});

<h1 class="trans">Animate my letter spacing</h1>
<input type="button" value="animate" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpolation between `normal` (the default value) and a length is not defined in the spec.  You want to transition from `0` to `10px`, not `normal` to `10px`.

Comment: I was under the assumption the default value was 0. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This still helped me one year later

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using css you can just .animate

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/8jAZy/9/

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {

   $("h1").animate({ "letter-spacing" : "10px"});

});
```

This is one method there may be another that works.